# Как сверстать сайт с авторизацией?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Как верстать сайт где допустим есть возможность входа в аккаунт, если пользователь допустим не вошёл, не все блоки отображаются. Этим же бэкенд занимается? А мне получается просто надо скрыть display none?

Comment: Вы это кто? Верстальщик фротенда или девелопер бекенда?

Answer (score 1):

Если верстальщику надо сверстать несколько видов одной и той же страницы, то так и надо делать: сверстать вариант для авторизованного пользователя и вариант для гостя. Обычно для верстки используется любой вариант подгрузки части шаблонов (например, через php include), для "сквозных блоков" или используется простой шаблонизатор. Это нужно только для тестирования верстки страниц.

Условия отображения шаблона в зависимости от серверных данных делает бэкенд-программист.

Answer (score 1):

Небезопасно просто сделать display:none, потому что любой, кто немного владеет css сможет это изменить из браузера.
По хорошему надо на бэкэнде сделать условие авторизованности, и если истина, то инклюдить ту часть кода, которую надо отобразить.